# How to download a csv file in CakePHP

Tags: php, file, cakephp, download

I have a csv file in my webroot/files..when ever I click on a link I want that csv file to be downloaded. I have written the following code and the file is also getting downloaded but there is no content in that downloaded file.so please help to get download the csv file with all content.

this ismy code:

```
public function downloadSamplefile()
{
    $name= "abc format.csv";    

    $file_path=HTTP_ROOT."app\webroot\files".$name;
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($name) . "\";");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));
    $file = @fopen($file_path);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile(HTTP_ROOT."app\webroot\files".$name); 

    @fclose($file);
    exit;

}
```

Comment: no need for `fopen` and `fclose`. Also `filesize` should be taking `$file_path` as argument, not `$name`

Comment: thanks steve..i have changed as u said but the same problem persists as i get a blank csv file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+download+file

Comment: How about simply reading the manual? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file There is copy and paste ready code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in path(var `$file_path`) I think.

**IF** `files` is a folder inside `app\webroot\` then $file_path variable will be

```
$file_path=ROOT."app\\webroot\\files\\".$name; // \ is also needed after 'file'
  //double \\ coz of escape char, try with single / also as follows
$file_path=ROOT."app/webroot/files/".$name;
  // best way to use cake php's functionality
$file_path=WWW_ROOT."files".DS.$name;
```

**And** change readfile and [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function parameter also:

```
readfile($file_path);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));
```

**Remove** following two line as @steve's comment:

```
$file = @fopen($file_path);
@fclose($file);
```

Because [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function itself OPEN then CLOSE the file automatically.

---

**If not work** then also try with:

```
$name="abc%20format.csv"; //space is encoded as %20 in URLs
```

Comment: thanks for your answer..Changed the code but the same problem persists and i am getting a blank csv file

Comment: @CHANDANPATTNAIK ok, in place of `HTTP_ROOT` use `ROOT` | **see my edited answer**

Comment: @CHANDANPATTNAIK,  Also debug by changing `if(!readfile($file_path)) echo "blank csv, was not able to read file, file path is-".$file_path;` | if you got msg in downloaded csv file that means there is problem in reading, that may be coz of wrong '$file_path'. don't use `HTTP_ROOT`/`ABS_ROOT` these are URLs which will be rewritten by `url rewrite` and will be changed. See file path is correct in downloaded CSV or NOT.

Comment: thanks @Adarsh Rajput got the desired result by changing HTTP_ROOT to WWW_ROOT .

Answer (score 1):

How about simply reading the manual? [There is a whole page dedicated to how to send files.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file) There is copy and paste ready code as well that shows how to do it right.

Also it doesn't make sense to push your file through php if it is available in the public accessible, unprotected webroot. Just link the file directly.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps

**Step-1**

in you controller create a method

```
public function downloadSamplefile() {
  $this->viewClass = 'Media';
  // Download app/webroot/files/example.csv
  $params = array(
     'id'        => 'example.csv',
     'name'      => 'example',
     'extension' => 'csv',
     'download'  => true,
     'path'      => APP . 'webroot' . DS. 'files'. DS  // file path
 );
 $this->set($params);
}
```

**step-2**

Go to your ctp file & write a link  as like

```
echo $this->Html->link(
'Download Sample',
array(
    'controller' => 'dashboards', // controller name
    'action' => 'downloadSamplefile',  //action name
    'full_base' => true
));
```

You will see a **Download Sample** link in your view file

When you click on **Download Sample** link it will be download a csv file which is stored in your app/webroot/files/exampl.csv

reference link [cakephp.org documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html)