# Create and download a csv file using cake php and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, export-to-csv

```
  public function userExport() {
    $list = array
        (
        "Peter,Griffin,Oslo,Norway",
        "Glenn,Quagmire,Oslo,Norway",
    );
    $file = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($list as $line) {
        fputcsv($file, explode(',', $line));
    }
    fclose($file);
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= "abc.csv"');
    $this->response->download($file);
    return;
```

}

The above controller was supposed to download the CSV file when I call this controller from my angular service. but it's showing the error

Error:

> The view for UsersController::userExport() was not found.

was the above code correct below is the angular service code to call this controller

```
   exportUsers: function (success, failure) {
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        cache: false,
                        url: 'api/users/userExport'
                    }).success(function (data) {
                        success && success(data);
                    }).error(function (data, status) {
                        failure && failure(data, status);
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **Error: The view for UsersController::userExport() was not found** error because corresponding .ctp file is not available in your Views folder.

Either create a user_export.ctp file under Users folder or just add the below line in your userExport function.

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

Comment: I had done a little change in the code "
    **$this->response->file($file, array('download' => true, 'name' => 'user.csv'));**"
but now I am getting any error  like this in response preview :- 
_Peter,Griffin,Oslo,Norway Glenn,Quagmire,Oslo,Norway
Warning (2): strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given [CORE/src/Network/Response.php, line 1438]_

Comment: I tried adding your code, but the download doesn't occur the request returned 200 status.

Comment: You can follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089568/how-to-download-a-csv-file-in-cakephp